# Why are &p and &a[0] different?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[4][2] = { {11, 12}, {21, 22}, {31, 32}, {41, 42} };
    int *p = a[0];

    printf("%d\n", *p);

    printf("%d\n", p); 

    printf("%d\n", a[0]);

    printf("%d\n", &p);

    printf("%d\n", &a[0]);

    printf("%d\n", a); 

    return 0;
}
```

Look at the above code.

In my understanding, since `p` equals `a[0]`, `&p` and `&a[0]` are supposed to have the same value.

But the actual output looks like this:

```
11
1772204208
1772204208
1772204200
1772204208
1772204208
```

Why are `&p` and `&a[0]` different?

What does `&p` represent?

Comment: With *p you are declaring a pointer and with &p you are getting the address of the pointer and normally its a register address of allocated memory, its different the address of the pointer and the value that the address contain.

Comment: Probably starting with `int[][]` is more confusing (because `&p` is `int**` and you imagine `&a[0]` to also be `int**`). Let's do one step back. An array `int a[]` decays to `int* p` which is also the address of its first element then `&a[0] == p`. Now you can see that `p != &p` (because, **generally speaking**, different variables have different memory locations) then `&a[0]` != &p`.

Comment: Sidenote: You are printing address incorrectly; you **must** use `%p` and cast to `void*`. For example: `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);`

Comment: Curious, what compiler/options are you using that does not warn about `printf("%d\n", p);` with something like "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]"?

Comment: gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` Is a pointer to an integer. It is stored in an address and it also stores an address.

Printing `p` will print the address `p` points to.

Printing `*p` prints the value `p` points to.

Printing `&p` prints the address of `p`, which is unique to `p` and was allocated in the moment it was declared.

```
int *p_2 = &p;
```

`p_2` will have the same value as `&p`

Every variable has its own unique address!

Comment: Minor: allocated  when `p` was _defined_, not _declared_.

Answer (score 12):

`&p` yields the address of the pointer `p` which obviously has to be different from the adress of `a[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a pointer pointing to array `a[0]`:

```
int *p = a[0];
```

In-memory view would be something like this:

```
        a[0][0] a[0][1]
        +-------------+
   a[0] |  11  |  12  |
        +-------------+
        ^
        |
        p
```

From this, it is clear that `p` and `a[0]` are the same pointer but `&p` and `&a[0]` are different.

Note:
`%d` is not the correct format specifier for printing a pointer. Instead, you should use `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding, since p equals a[0], &p and &a[0] are supposed to have the same value.

`p` and `a[0]` indeed have the same value, but this does not imply that they are identical. Just like if you have 2 variables `i` and `j` defined as `int i = 0, j = 0;` it is true that `i` and `j` have the same value but obviously have different addresses.

Note also that your code has undefined behavior because `%d` is not an appropriate conversion specifier for a pointer to `int`. You should `%p` and pass the pointer cast as `(void*)` or `%llu` and cast the pointer as `(unsigned long long)(uintptr_t)p`. `uintptr_t` is defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[4][2] = { {11, 12}, {21, 22}, {31, 32}, {41, 42} };
    int *p = a[0];

    printf("   *p: %d\n", *p);
    printf("    p: %p\n", (void*)p); 
    printf(" a[0]: %p\n", (void*)a[0]);
    printf("   &p: %p\n", (void*)&p);
    printf("&a[0]: %p\n", (void*)&a[0]);
    printf("    a: %p\n", (void*)a); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   *p: 11
    p: 0x7fff5144d950
 a[0]: 0x7fff5144d950
   &p: 0x7fff5144d948
&a[0]: 0x7fff5144d950
    a: 0x7fff5144d950
```

As you can see, the array `a` has the same address as its first row `a[0]` and this is also the address of `a[0][0]` which `p` points to.

`&a[0]` is different from `a[0]`: same address but different type: `a[0]` is an array of 2 `int`, `&a[0]` is the address of an array of 2 `int`. `&a[0] + 1` points to `a[1]` whereas `a[0] + 1` points to `a[0][1]`.

I'm sorry I cannot explain this in simpler terms, it is very confusing to take the address of an array: you can achieve a fairly advanced level of C programming without ever needing to understand these subtleties. Just remember that arrays decay as pointers their first element in most expression contexts (except as an argument to `sizeof`) and never use the addressof operator (`&`) on an array.

Answer (score 1):

In C "&" means "address of".It means &p means address of p.One thing to remember is that a pointer is also a variable which can store the address of another variable.Property of C programming is that whenever a new variable is declared,it will allocate a different memory location(address) for that variable to store the value of that variable.So variable value is different from variable address.In your code both a[0] and p are different variables.So both have different memory locations.

so try to understand the following

int *p=a[0];
The above line meaning is that the address of a[0] is stored into variable p.It means value of p is the address of a[0].So p is equal to &a[0].

Now consider below code(Not in your code)
int ar[10];
int *k=ar;
The above two lines code is a valid code in C. Consider the second line of code.since ar is assigned k,we have to understand one thing that both are of same type variables.It means ar is also pointer.The ar represents the address of the first element in ar array i.e,a[0].it means ar and &a[0] both are same.
If we relate above things to your code,we conclude that

&a[0],p,a are same which represent the same address.
*p,a[0] are same which represent the value of first element in the array.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: *int *p=a[0]; The above line meaning is that the address of a[0] is stored into variable p* actually, because `a[0]` is an array, it means that the address of `a[0][0]` is stored into `p`. `p == &a[0][0]` is true, but `p == &a[0]` is a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer, which is a variable containing a memory address.

The operator `&` gives the address of the object you're using it on, so `&p` means the address of the pointer.